# How to make all input boxes ordered in a straight line?

Tags: html, css

I have been wanting all my input boxes ordered in a straight line, I have been following to make a website from a picture, and I wanted to know how to make the boxes straight like this:

[image]

So far my website looks like this:

[image]

Notice how all the input boxes look messy and unaligned? What can I do to make it look cleaner?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>int222_162d16 - Assignment 3 - Home Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css"   type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sitecss.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="https://zenit.senecac.on.ca/~emile.ohan/cgi-bin/cardApplication.cgi" method="post" id="application" name="application">
        <fieldset>
        <legend class="t"><img src="https://zenit.senecac.on.ca/~emile.ohan/int222/bank-logo.png"alt="Assignment #3" />Seneca Bank - Credit Card Application</legend>

          <div class="clearfix">
            <aside class="l">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Primary Applicant's Information</legend>
                First Name*    <input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" size="20" maxlength="20" autofocus="autofocus"> <br />
                Surname*       <input type="text" name="sName" id="sName" size="20" maxlength="30"> <br />
                Date of Birth* <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" size="10" maxlength="9" placeholder="MMMDDYYYY"> <br />
                Email Address* <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="20" maxlength="60"> <br />
                Phone No.*     <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="20" maxlength="12"> <br />
            </fieldset>
            </aside>

            <section class="s">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Primary Applicant's Address</legend>
                Home Address*  <input type="text" name="address" id="address" size="30" maxlength="60"> 
                Apt.            <input type="text" name="apt" id="apt" size="5" maxlength="4"> <br />
                City*          <input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="20" maxlength="40"> <br />
                Province*      <select id="province" name="province" size="2">
                                   <optgroup label="Province">
                                       <option value="">(Select a Province)</option>
                                       <option value="Alberta">Alberta</option>
                                       <option value="British Columbia">British Columbia</option>
                                       <option value="Manitoba">Manitoba</option>
                                       <option value="New Brunswick">New Brunswick</option>
                                       <option value="Newfoundland & Labrador">Newfoundland & Labrador</option>
                                       <option value="Nova Scotia">Nova Scotia</option>
                                       <option value="Ontario">Ontario</option>
                                       <option value="Prince Edward Island">PE</option>
                                       <option value="Quebec">Quebec</option>
                                       <option value="Saskatchewan">Saskatchewan</option>
                                   </optgroup>
                                   <optgroup label="Territory">
                                       <option value="Northwest Territories">Northwest Territories</option>
                                       <option value="Nunavut">Nunavut</option>
                                       <option value="Yukon">Yukon</option>
                                   </optgroup>
                               </select>
            Postal Code*       <input type="text" name="postal" id="postal" size="8" maxlength="7" placeholder="ANA NAN"> <br />
            </fieldset>
            </section>

            <aside class="r">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Housing Status</legend>
                Do you             <input type="checkbox" name="hStatus" id="s01" value="Own" />Own the property
                                   <input type="checkbox" name="hStatus" id="s02" value="Rent" />Rent the property<br />
                $Monthly Payment*  <input type="text" name="payment" id="payment" size="8" maxlength="6"> <br />
                Monthly Income*    <input type="text" name="income" id="income" size="8" maxlength="6"> <br />
                Years at current location*  <input type="text" name="currYears" id="currYears" size="3" maxlength="2"> <br />
                Pre-authorized Code*        <input type="text" name="preCode" id="preCode" size="8"> <br />
            </fieldset>
            </aside>
          </div>

          <div class="clearfix">
            <section class="s">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Reserved - See below</legend>
                <p><b>If you submit your application with errors and/or omissions, a list of errors and/or omissions will show here. Make the corrections and re-submit.</b></p>
                <p><b>If you continue to have a problem submitting your application, make a note of the Reference No. and call us at 1-800-010-2000.</b></p>
            </fieldset>
            </section>


            <aside class="l">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Credit Check / Email Consent</legend>
                I consent to have a credit check performed<br /> 
                                                            <input type="checkbox" name="creditCheck" id="c01" value="Yes" />Yes
                                                           <input type="checkbox" name="creditCheck" id="c02" value="No" />No
                <br />                                         

                I consent to have email messages sent to me<br />
                                                            <input type="radio" name="emailConsent" id="m01" value="Yes" />Yes
                                                           <input type="radio" name="emailConsent" id="m02" value="No" />No
                <br />                                         
                Submitted on : CURRENT Date

                Ref. #              <input type="text" name="refNo" id="refNo" size="8" readonly="readonly"> <br />
                <!--Submit Application--> <input type="submit" value="Submit Application">
                <!--Start Over-->         <input type="reset" value="Start Over">
                                          <input type="hidden" name="hName" id="hName" value="Mahmood"> <br />
                                          <input type="hidden" name="hId" id="hId" value="int222_162d16"> <br />
            </fieldset>
            </aside>

          </div>



        </fieldset>
        </form>


        <footer class=f>
            <a href="../">My zenit Account</a>   <a href="javascript/">My JavaScript</a>   <a href="css/">My CSS</a>   <a href="honesty.html">My Honesty</a> 
            <script>
                var dt=new Date(document.lastModified);   // Get document last modified date
                document.write('<p>This page was last updated on '+dt.toLocaleString()) + '</p>';
            </script>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
footer.f
{
    text-align: center;
}

legend 
{ 
    border: 4px groove #ff0000;
    background-color: #9999ff; 
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 15px; 
    text-shadow:0.1em 0.1em 0.01em #333;
}

legend.t
{
     vertical-align: top;
}

fieldset
{
    border-color:#F00;
    border-style: solid;
}

html, body 
{
    max-width: 100%;
    /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
    margin:0;
}

aside.r 
{
  float: right;
  width: 31%;
  margin: 1%;

}

aside.l
{
  float: left;
  width: 31%;
  margin: 1%;



}
section.s /*shadow on sections*/
{

    width: 31%;
    margin: 1%;
    display: inline-block;

}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: The question is too broad. A solution could be... the table.

Comment: I will post my html and css code so you know what I did specifically to make this webpage.

Comment: So if I understand you right, you want to have all boxes the same height depending on the tallest one. Well you have 3 options, the easy one: use flex-box. The not so easy but working one: use a table. The messy one: use fixed height values.

Comment: I suggest learning about CSS, specifically about `display:table` and/or `display:flex` a.k.a. flex-box.

Comment: Ok then, have you made any attempts to solve the problem?

Comment: I am very new to html and css, what I understand about paragraphs is that you cannot use multiple spaces to the paragraph as it would show only as one, which is what I tried to do, however it didn't work, so it's why I actually came here to ask this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HTML table will do all the aligning for you.

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>First Name*</td>    
  <td><input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" size="20" maxlength="20" autofocus="autofocus"></td></tr>
  
  <tr><td>Surname*</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="sName" id="sName" size="20" maxlength="30"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Date of Birth*</td>    
  <td><input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" size="10" maxlength="9" placeholder="MMMDDYYYY"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Email Address*</td>    
  <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="20" maxlength="60"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Phone No.*</td>    
  <td><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="20" maxlength="12"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML tables:

```
<table>
   <tr><td>First Name*</td><td><input type='text' /></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Surname*</td><td><input type='text' /></td></tr>
</table>
```